# Oracle Spatial issue PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_GEOMETRY'

Tags: oracle, spatial

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE cola_markets (
  mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(32),
  shape SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

I tried to insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
  1,
  'cola_a',
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3), -- one rectangle (1003 = exterior)
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7) -- only 2 points needed to
          -- define rectangle (lower left and upper right) with
          -- Cartesian-coordinate data
  )
);
```

I got the error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_GEOMETRY'
```

If I switch SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY to NULL:

```
INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
  1,
  'cola_a',
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL, -- one rectangle (1003 = exterior)
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7) -- only 2 points needed to
          -- define rectangle (lower left and upper right) with
          -- Cartesian-coordinate data
  )
);
```

I don't get error:

```
1 row inserted.
```

What's the issue here? Why can't I use SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY?

Comment: The code you pasted into your question gives me no error in Oracle 18c. It worked just fine.

Comment: Works for version 11gR2 , and I know it should work for 10gR1 , too.

Comment: It used to work for me, then suddenly Sql Developer didn't recognize SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY anymore. I deleted the Sql Developer folder, downloaded it again, I removed everything under 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer', but nothing helped.

Comment: Works also on 20c. Should have nothing to do with sqldev. Are you sure of your code? (i.e. there's no interfering hidden chars, ...)